# How to create a recursive function that only calls itself x number of times

Tags: c, recursion

I want to create a recursive function "rec" which is given a variable "var".
The variable is then used in a calculation like
var = 3 * var
the function is then supposed to call itself
to repeat that process.

But now i only want that process repeated a certain number of times
for Example the recursion is supposed to repeat itself 12 times.
How do i do that.

I tried using a new variable "i" that would be incremented each recursion.
after the 12th recursion the function should return the variable "var" and not call itself again.

This did not work though, the function "rec" just returned the value it was given without actually looping or incrementing i.

Is the solution with new variable "i" even valid or did i just somehow mess it up.
if it is not doable that way, are there any other solutions to define how deep the recursion should go?

(i know that doing this process with a loop is easier but i want to understand
recursion a bit more and understand why this doesnt work.)

Exemplementary codeCODE:

```
int rec(int var){
    int i = 0;
    if(i = 12){
        return var;
    }else{
        i++;
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            var = 3 * var;
        }
    }
    return rec(var);
}
```

Comment: It seems you just want `return var;` instead of `return rec(var);`

Comment: Please pass the recursion counter to the function. `int i = 0;` is a a distinct local variable in each incarnation, and will never be `(i > 12)`.

Comment: Looks like `return rec(var);` was correct, but calling to `rec(var)` inside `if` is wrong. Otherwise recursive function is called exactly with the same argument again. It might cause an infinite loop

Comment: @WeatherVane could you elaborate further, now that you said it it toatlly makes sense that i would be local for each recursion. But how would i go about passing the recursion counter?

Comment: What is the routine supposed to compute? Focus on that before working on how many times it is called.

Comment: Just pass `int i` as input parameter to the function (instead of declaring it locally inside the function), and when you recursively call the function, increment it by 1, i.e., `return rec(var, i + 1);`.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbbm Thank you, that fixed the problem :) have a goodn night